# Importing an Artifact stored in an Artifactory as maven into IntelliJ does not work

Tags: intellij-idea, artifactory

So I've got my artifactory, it's the oss version, and I've uploaded something named UltimateChatAPI (Yes, ultimate, don't judge, I'm not asking for this.) into libs-snapshot-local, it's the version 1.9-R0.1-SNAPSHOT and it appears to be there, I can download and view the classes' source, but when I import it into IntelliJ by it's Maven, I see the packages but I have no access to classes inside IntelliJ, this is the Maven code I use to import it:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>libs-snapshot-local</id>
        <url>http://192.168.178.53:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>UltimateChatAPI</groupId>
        <artifactId>UltimateChatAPI</artifactId>
        <version>1.9-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The IP is good and the link too (used in browser, it resolves to the index where there is a downloadable copy of what I want). And the groupID and artifactID and version is as set when deploying the artifact, but it just happens I cannot use the classes, any help or tutorial to importing an Artifactory hosted artifact into IntelliJ please?..

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so, I've just solved it and this is what happenned, IntelliJ cache old versions of my trials so nothing ever updated, so I went in C:/Users/Me/.m2/repository and deleted the folder with my Group ID, I reloaded the IntelliJ maven by removing the dependency and putting it back for auto import and it happenned to work!